# Xbox controller emulator

Tags: controller, emulation, xbox

Is there any way to emulate an xbox controller for my pc? I need to test my app, but I don't have access to a wired controller for a while! :( I'd like to just emulate the controller buttons and joysticks via normal keyboard buttons or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

once look at these links may it helps you 
[xbox emulator for pc](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqY-zEN9rZk)
[xbox contoller](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7ucYkLEGjM&ei=b1TVUKiqIcT9rAfphoHwDw&usg=AFQjCNE4qEIjJf6In2RfA4tZNLB9e8Gp6w&sig2=_P4OV_8_MyMV-rgxq6XQmQ&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bmk)